# Поиск по всему массиву

Tags: php

Есть массив вида:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(*) "test.ru-111.11111.111"
  [1]=> string(*) "site2.ru-2222.22.222"
  [2]=> string(*) "test.in-333.333.333"
}
```

Мне нужно найти в нем значение (точнее номер, под которым записано в массиве это значение), например - `test.ru`, делаю так:

```
array_search('test.ru', $array);
```

не находит. A

```
array_search('test.ru-111.11111.111', $array);
```

находит.

Но оно понятно почему... Как сделать чтобы находило по слову которое идет до `-`.

При условии, что массив `$array` нельзя выводить в цикле.

//////////////////////////

```
foreach($new_arr as $list_d_ip) {
    $iskomii = explode('-', $list_d_ip);
    $iskomii = str_replace(' ', '', $iskomii[0]);

    $patt = '/'.$iskomii.'-/';
    $ss = preg_grep($patt, $array);

    var_dump($ss);

}
```

> ```
> array(3) { [0]=> string(26) "zesiduwyk.ru -11.11.11.11 " [1]=> string(27) "edeziragaj.ru -2222.222.22 " [2]=> string(13) "test.ru-00000" }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-grep.php), чтобы искать в массиве с помощью регулярного выражения.

```
$array = [
    "test.ru-111.11111.111",
    "site2.ru-2222.22.222",
    "test.in-333.333.333",
];

var_dump(preg_grep('/test.ru-/', $array));

# Вывод:
array(1) {
  [0]=> string(21) "test.ru-111.11111.111"
}
```

Comment: `^` в начало бы добавить не помешало

Comment: @teran, хм, в начало регулярного выражения? Честно говоря, почти не работаю с ними, не знаю подробностей.

Comment: почему-то находит только последний элемент. у меня есть массив в котором записаны домены которые нужно найти, вывожу так `foreach($new_arr as $list_d_ip) { var_dump(preg_grep('/'.$list_d_ip.'-/', $array)); }`

Comment: @Денис, попробуйте `'/'.$list_d_ip.'-/'` изменить на - `"/$list_d_ip-/"`, либо вынести шаблон поиска строки как отдельную переменную.

Comment: не помогает... как быть?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос в самый конец

Comment: добавил в конец вопроса

Comment: Ну я так заметил, что `zesiduwyk.ru -11....` есть пробел между `.ru -11.`, тоесть, если убрать, то в цикле выведется все три примера из массива в конце вопроса. Возможно в этом и проблема. Если да, то надо поправить регулярное выражение.